# Id like to create subclass' in python one mimes a users previous input, the other cycles a series of choices

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am attempting to code a rock paper scissors game in Python3. I was provided some starter code and am attempting to accomplish some extra things with the code. like providing different player classes, announcing a winner, keeping score etc. I'm finding good and probably more simple ways of coding a this kind of game but this was the format I was presented with and I can't seem to find any good examples of the code written this way. aside from that I basically have it all down except 2 things where I have to create additional player class types. The game plays for 3 rounds and announces the winner at the end.

1)I'm trying to code in a player class that remembers what the user input in the previous round and plays that as their choice of rock, paper or scissors.

2)class that remembers what move it played last round, and cycles through the different moves. like if it played rock it would then play paper, then scissors.

3)(this one isn't quite so important) but I'm trying to figure out how to continue to prompt the player to spell their pick correctly because as of at the moment it just prompts you one time and if you spell it incorrectly again it just takes the input as "none"

```
    moves = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

    import random

    class Player:
        score = 0
        def move(self):
            return 'rock'

        def learn(self, my_move, their_move):
            pass

    #    def move(self):
    #        return 'paper'

    #    def learn(self, my_move, their_move):
    #        pass

    #    def move(self):
    #        return 'scissors'

    #    def learn(self, my_move, their_move):
    #        pass

    class RandomPlayer(Player):
        def __init__(self):
            Player.__init__(self)

        def move (self):
            return random.choice(moves)

    class HumanPlayer(Player):
        def __init__(self):
            Player.__init__(self)

        def move (self):
            x = input("choose rock, paper or scissors:")
            if x not in (moves):
                x = input("check your spelling and try again:")
                return(x)
            else:
                return(x)

    #class ReflectPlayer(Player):
    #    def __init__(self):
    #        Player.__init__(self)
    #       
    #    def move (self): 

    #class CyclePlayer(Player):
    #    def __init__(self):
    #        Player.__init__(self)
    #       
    #    def move (self): 

    def beats(one, two):
        return ((one == 'rock' and two == 'scissors') or
                (one == 'scissors' and two == 'paper') or
                (one == 'paper' and two == 'rock'))

    class Game:

        def __init__(self, p1, p2):
            self.p1 = p1
            self.p2 = p2

        def play_round(self):
            move1 = self.p1.move()
            move2 = self.p2.move()
            print(f"Player 1: {move1}  Player 2: {move2}")
            self.p1.learn(move1, move2)
            self.p2.learn(move2, move1)
            if beats(move1, move2):
                print("player 1 wins this round")
                self.p1.score += 1
            elif beats(move2, move1):
                print("player 2 wins this round")
                self.p2.score += 1   
            else:
                print("A Tie!")
            print(f"Scores, Player 1: {self.p1.score} Player 2:      
    {self.p2.score}")

        def play_game(self):
            print("Game start!")
            for round in range(3):
                print(f"Round {round}:")
                self.play_round()
            print("Game over!")

            if self.p1.score > self.p2.score:
                print ("Player 1 Wins the Game!")
            elif self.p2.score > self.p1.score:
                print ("Player 2 Wins the Game!")
            else:
            print("a TIE!? it must be settled with a FIGHT TO THE DEATH!")          



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        game = Game(HumanPlayer(), RandomPlayer())
        game.play_game()
```

Comment: It seems a big job.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the frequency of moves by human player and accordingly make a move. A simple approach can be you make a move based on `max` of the human move frequency.

```
class RandomPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self):
        Player.__init__(self)
        self.human_player_history = {}  # stores the frequency of human player moves
        for move in moves:
            self.human_player_history[move] = 0

    def move(self):
        max_move = max(self.human_player_history.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
        if max_move == 'rock':
            return 'paper'
        if max_move == 'scissors':
            return 'rock'
        if max_move == 'paper':
            return 'rock'

    def learn(self, my_move, their_move):
        self.human_player_history[their_move] += 1
```

Comment: This could use the `collections.Counter()` class from the standard library.